# To get random image from Parse

Tags: swift, image, random, pfquery

I tried many code asked in stack overflow but almost all of them is for core data not from Parse.

I try to get random image from Parse at kombin.swift.
Then with a button to change the image randomly.
Which code should I use to have image randomly at first and then change the image(with a button) randomly?

This is my ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var placeNameArray = [String]()
    var chosenPlace = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        getData()
    }

    func getData() {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Places")
        query.findObjectsInBackground  { (objects, error) in
            if error != nil {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(okButton)
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)
            } else {
                self.placeNameArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                for object in objects! {
                    self.placeNameArray.append(object.object(forKey: "name") as! String)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "1to4"
        {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ViewController4
            destinationVC.selectedPlace = self.chosenPlace
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        self.chosenPlace = placeNameArray[indexPath.row]
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "1to4", sender: nil)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = placeNameArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return placeNameArray.count
    }

    @IBAction func ekle(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "1to2", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

my kombin.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class kombin: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var imageArray = [PFFile]()
    var placeNameArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        func randomImage() -> UIImage {
            let unsignedArrayCount = UInt32(imageArray.count)
            let unsignedRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(unsignedArrayCount)
            let randomNumber = Int(unsignedRandomNumber)
            return UIImage(named: placeNameArray[randomNumber])!
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your question how to get a random object from an array ? It's a bit unclear what's working and what's not from your description

Comment: @nathan yes. The issue is; I could make an array manually, it works but I want to call a random image fron the server every time when the button is pressed.

Comment: What do you mean by "call a random image" ? What's the problem with your code ? You haven't provided a detailed account of the problem. Are you getting an exception/error ? Something not working as it should ?

Comment: I need a function to define on a button to change the image in the "imageView". Whenever user push the button, I want to change image randomly. When I check the similar situations, nobody tried to use the database. They upload the images to xcode and form an array and they use switch function and arc4random to change image randomly. But ı want to use images in Parse. The images in the parse are uploaded by other users.

Comment: And why isn't `randomImage()` working ? The issue might be related with how to load a remote image instead of how to get a random object from an array

Comment: Maybe I did a mistake with let randomNumber = Int(unsignedRandomNumber)

Comment: Please debug your code before asking, try setting a breakpoint in `return UIImage(named: ...)` and check that the previous vars are correct. Also, why are you declaring `randomImage()` inside `viewDidLoad()` ? randomImage is never used. And where are you using "kombin.swift" (should be named "Kombin.swift")